# Email generated from VisualForce email template has unneccessary white space

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have a Visual Force email template that shows Products ordered and Tracking.

In a nutshell:
Tracking / Products both exist on Sales Order Lines for a specific Sales Order.
Products have a Line_Status__C that isn't null.
Tracking is on the Description field.  All other fields are null

The issue:
It seems the tracking numbers create a blank space after Products and Products cause a blank space to be shown before tracking.

Images/Code below.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am not a developer and got help with this code.

[image]
[image]

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Purchase_Order__c} Shipped" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Order_Header__c">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <body style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS'">
            <h4>
                Just letting you know Purchase Order - {!relatedTo.Purchase_Order__c}, 
                was shipped today.
            </h4>
            <hr style="border: solid thin #0099CC; margin-top: -18px;" />

            <br />

            <br />

            <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                        <b>Stock Code</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                        <b>Description</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                        <b>Shipped Qty</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                        <b>Status</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Order_Detail__r}" var="lineItem">
                    <tr style="display:{!IF(lineItem.Line_Status__c != null, '', 'none')}">
                        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0099CC;">
                            <b>{!lineItem.Stock_Code__c}</b>
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0099CC;">
                            {!lineItem.Description__c}
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0099CC;">
                            {!lineItem.Shipped_Qty__c}
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0099CC;">
                            {!lineItem.Line_Status__c}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </table>

            <br/>

            <h4>
                Tracking Code: 
                <strong>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Order_Detail__r}" var="lineItem">
                        <BR>{!IF(ISBLANK(lineItem.Stock_Code__c), lineItem.Description__c, NULL)}</BR>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </strong>
            </h4>
        </body>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this is because of the way you have your table defined where you include cellpadding:

```
<table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
```

This padding creates a 5 pixel "buffer" or "space" both before and after the contents of each cell. If you don't want any spacing before or after the contents of a cell, remove the `cellpadding` from your table definition or set it to `0`.

**EDIT**

Even though you've specified `style="border-collapse"`, your borders will style have a width unless you set `border-width` to 'none' or 'hidden'.

> None: No border; the computed border width is zero.
>
> Hidden: Same as 'none', except in terms of border conflict resolution for table elements.

Now, because you're doing something with the border-bottom, you may need to set the property to `none` or `hidden` for just the `border-right`, `border-left` and `border-top`.

You may discover that it's best to also keep `border-top` and continue to use `border-collapse` with your table as well. You'll need to try it to see what works best for you. My instincts tell me that this is likely to be the case. Browser and email reader behavior can vary and your templates will be safest using CSS 2.1 as I've specified here.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same thing for either of these:
<table cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%"> 
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">

Comment: You don't have any stylesheets of any kind applied to this that aren't shown do you?

Comment: No style sheets, just the VF template.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I am not CSS expert.  Is this what I should try?

<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border-width="hidden" border-right="hidden" border-left="hidden" border-top="hidden">

I had no luck with this.

The odd thing is with my Yahoo email as viewed on my cell phone I see a Gap because the "Tracking Code" text and the tracking numbers and no gaps elsewhere, but that was always the case.

Comment: Don't use border-width="hidden". That's not valid CSS. I would recommend using the "none" instead of "hidden" for the other border border left, right, and top. If you do that, you won't need border-collapse. If that doesn't work, then add it back in and remove the boder-top="none" to see if that fixes it for you. (each top and bottom border will collapse into each other).

Comment: Not sure what else to try, neither of these work?

Comment: <table style="border-width=none" border-right="none" border-left="none" border-top="none">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border-width="none" border-right="none" border-left="none">

Comment: border-width=none applies to ALL borders. No need to specify left and right if you use that.

Comment: This doesn't work either... <table style="border-width=none">

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to put the css inside each of the 4 `<td>` tags you have. But you only want to use it for the border-left and border-right since you have a border-bottom specified. In fact, the border-bottom tags in those cells may be what's causing the css in the `<table>` declaration to be ignored. If that doesn't work, I don't know what else to suggest. I wouldn't use border-width=none in the table declaration. Only for the left & right.